# Thread to update DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, datagridview

I have a windows form with a `button` and a `datagridview`. When I select the `button` a thread is initiated that does something and eventually fills my `datagridview`. The problem is that the `datagridview` is not filled.

What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
Private MyCreateStructureFromSampleXMLTread As Thread

Private Sub ButtonCreateStructureFromSampleXML_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonCreateStructureFromSampleXML.Click
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    MyCreateStructureFromSampleXMLTread = New Thread(AddressOf ModuleXML_MESSAGE_STRUCTURE.CreateStructureFromSampleXML)
    MyCreateStructureFromSampleXMLTread.IsBackground = True
    MyCreateStructureFromSampleXMLTread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
    MyCreateStructureFromSampleXMLTread.Start()
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub
```

Threading:

```
    Friend Sub CreateStructureFromSampleXML()
    FormUTool.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    Try
        If ModuleFileHandling.OpenFile(Application.StartupPath, "Select XML File", ".xml", "XML File (*.xml)|*.xml") = True Then
            ParseXMLFile(PublicUToolVariable.MyOpenedFile)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
    ModuleXML_MESSAGE_STRUCTURE.AlignElementPaths(PublicUToolVariable.MyAccessConnection)
    ModuleXML_MESSAGE_STRUCTURE.XML_MESSAGE_STRUCTUREFillDataGridView(PublicUToolVariable.MyAccessConnection)
    FormUTool.Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you put a try catch block around the method? most likely you are getting an exception whereby the thread is trying to access a UI component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to fill the `DataGridView` from a thread other than the UI thread. That is what you are doing wrong. UI elements have thread affinity requirements that mandate that they are only ever accessed from the thread that created them.

Change your strategy so that you are loading and parsing the XML in a worker thread and then send that data to the UI thread and let the UI thread fill the `DataGridView`. That is the standard approach. You can use the `BackgroundWorker` class. The `DoWork` event handler will execute on a worker thread and the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler will run on the UI thread so all of the marshaling is handled for you.

Comment: Brian, thanks a million for the pointer. With your help I managed to find a good example here: <http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?680130-Correct-way-to-use-the-BackgroundWorker>